# How to connect an API hosted on AWS Elastic Beanstalk to a MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, docker, architecture, web-hosting

## Context

I have been developing a website using React for the client-side and Python for the API which uses Flask. My database is written using Python and SQLAlchemy.  I am currently learning how to host these using AWS.

Frontend summary:

- The React client-side is hosted in a S3 bucket.
- I have setup a CloudFlare DNS and bought a domain using Porkbun.
- I use CloudFlare Distributions to route requests to my domain to the S3 Bucket.
- HTTP requests from my React Redux actions are sent to my API endpoints, which are hosted onto Elastic Beanstalk.

Backend summary:

- I have hosted my Flask application and API to Elastic Beanstalk.
- The API routes interact with a MySQL database using SQLAlchemy.
- The MySQL database is on a MySQL server that runs on my local machine.

## Problem

How can my API, which is hosted onto Elastic Beanstalk, talk to my MySQL database?

## Possible Solutions

- Should I migrate the MySQL database to an RDS database?
- Is there a way to connect my API to the MySQL database on my local MySQL server?
- Should I host the MySQL database in a Docker container?

## What I am trying to understand

I am learning about web architecture and would like to understand the benefits of different configurations.

Comment: you can use [aws](https://aws.amazon.com/free/) to host your database and then get the username, password , database name and repace it in your database_uri.

Comment: In what ways should I host my database to AWS? Should I use RDS? If so, does that mean the MySQL database on my local machine is no longer needed?

Comment: ya you can use RDS and the database on local machine won't connect to it so it is not needed

Comment: I see, so one possible method would be to migrate the data from the MySQL on my local machine, to RDS. Thank you for your help. I would still like to understand what other benefits there may be for running a Docker instance with a MySQL database (and how to connect my API to that).

Comment: sorry, I don't know about docker.